# How can I make a custom calendar in Flutter? without using any plugins

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-layout

[image: How can I make this.]

I tried date picker but I am unable to put those next and the cancel button with the layout and icon in the top right corner.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way? I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat belated answer, but it may still be useful for others or for you in your future projects.

[image]

Consider the calendar widget as a simple layout, consisting of:

- A header with two Text widgets displaying the selected date and selected month, and two buttons.
- A body with columns and rows containing Text widgets.
- A bottom section with two buttons.

The most challenging part is the body.

To create this part, we need:

- A list of weeks.
- Each week as a list of 7 days.

The DateTime class has an instance method called weekday, which returns the day of the week, with Monday as 1, Tuesday as 2, etc.

Additionally, we can create a small `DateTime` extension to help us get the first day of the month `DateTime(year, month, 1)` (the '1' is not necessary; I've added it to explain the idea), add or subtract months `DateTime addMonth(int count) => DateTime(year, month + count, day)`, and compare dates `bool isSameDate(DateTime date) => year == date.year && month == date.month && day == date.day`.

The other components are relatively straightforward. Here is the entire code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

extension DateTimeExt on DateTime {
  DateTime get monthStart => DateTime(year, month);
  DateTime get dayStart => DateTime(year, month, day);

  DateTime addMonth(int count) {
    return DateTime(year, month + count, day);
  }

  bool isSameDate(DateTime date) {
    return year == date.year && month == date.month && day == date.day;
  }

  bool get isToday {
    return isSameDate(DateTime.now());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late DateTime selectedMonth;

  DateTime? selectedDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedMonth = DateTime.now().monthStart;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 450,
          width: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              _Header(
                selectedMonth: selectedMonth,
                selectedDate: selectedDate,
                onChange: (value) => setState(() => selectedMonth = value),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: _Body(
                  selectedDate: selectedDate,
                  selectedMonth: selectedMonth,
                  selectDate: (DateTime value) => setState(() {
                    selectedDate = value;
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              _Bottom(
                selectedDate: selectedDate,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Body({
    required this.selectedMonth,
    required this.selectedDate,
    required this.selectDate,
  });

  final DateTime selectedMonth;
  final DateTime? selectedDate;

  final ValueChanged<DateTime> selectDate;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = CalendarMonthData(
      year: selectedMonth.year,
      month: selectedMonth.month,
    );

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: const [
            Text('M'),
            Text('T'),
            Text('W'),
            Text('T'),
            Text('F'),
            Text('S'),
            Text('S'),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.pink[200],
            ),
            for (var week in data.weeks)
              Row(
                children: week.map((d) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: _RowItem(
                      hasRightBorder: false,
                      date: d.date,
                      isActiveMonth: d.isActiveMonth,
                      onTap: () => selectDate(d.date),
                      isSelected: selectedDate != null &&
                          selectedDate!.isSameDate(d.date),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _RowItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _RowItem({
    required this.hasRightBorder,
    required this.isActiveMonth,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.date,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  final bool hasRightBorder;
  final bool isActiveMonth;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool isSelected;

  final DateTime date;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int number = date.day;
    final isToday = date.isToday;
    final bool isPassed = date.isBefore(DateTime.now());

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 35,
        decoration: isSelected
            ? const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink, shape: BoxShape.circle)
            : isToday
                ? BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
        child: Text(
          number.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: isPassed
                  ? isActiveMonth
                      ? Colors.grey
                      : Colors.transparent
                  : isActiveMonth
                      ? Colors.black
                      : Colors.grey[300]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Header extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Header({
    required this.selectedMonth,
    required this.selectedDate,
    required this.onChange,
  });

  final DateTime selectedMonth;
  final DateTime? selectedDate;

  final ValueChanged<DateTime> onChange;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
              'Selected date: ${selectedDate == null ? 'non' : "${selectedDate!.day}.${selectedDate!.month}.${selectedDate!.year}"}'),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Month: ${selectedMonth.month + 1}/${selectedMonth.year}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  onChange(selectedMonth.addMonth(-1));
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_left_sharp),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  onChange(selectedMonth.addMonth(1));
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right_sharp),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Bottom extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Bottom({
    required this.selectedDate,
  });

  final DateTime? selectedDate;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(selectedDate);
          },
          child: const Text('save'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('cancel'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CalendarMonthData {
  final int year;
  final int month;

  int get daysInMonth => DateUtils.getDaysInMonth(year, month);
  int get firstDayOfWeekIndex => 0;

  int get weeksCount => ((daysInMonth + firstDayOffset) / 7).ceil();

  const CalendarMonthData({
    required this.year,
    required this.month,
  });

  int get firstDayOffset {
    final int weekdayFromMonday = DateTime(year, month).weekday - 1;

    return (weekdayFromMonday - ((firstDayOfWeekIndex - 1) % 7)) % 7 - 1;
  }

  List<List<CalendarDayData>> get weeks {
    final res = <List<CalendarDayData>>[];
    var firstDayMonth = DateTime(year, month, 1);
    var firstDayOfWeek = firstDayMonth.subtract(Duration(days: firstDayOffset));

    for (var w = 0; w < weeksCount; w++) {
      final week = List<CalendarDayData>.generate(
        7,
        (index) {
          final date = firstDayOfWeek.add(Duration(days: index));

          final isActiveMonth = date.year == year && date.month == month;

          return CalendarDayData(
            date: date,
            isActiveMonth: isActiveMonth,
            isActiveDate: date.isToday,
          );
        },
      );
      res.add(week);
      firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.add(const Duration(days: 7));
    }
    return res;
  }
}

class CalendarDayData {
  final DateTime date;
  final bool isActiveMonth;
  final bool isActiveDate;

  const CalendarDayData({
    required this.date,
    required this.isActiveMonth,
    required this.isActiveDate,
  });
}
```

Comment: you can use intl package to have better date formatting.
I didn't add it to make to not use external packages.